# How to set default value for emit() parameter in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I want set a default value like this for parameter :

```
$this-> emit(‘mount’ ,$id, default_value=1);

how I can do this?
```

Comment: You put the default value on the listener.

Comment: I do that: $this->emit('mount' ,$id ?? 1);

Comment: Put the default value In the function you use to listen to that emitted event.

Comment: Put the default value while defining the function `public function emit(‘mount’ ,$id, default_value=1)`

Comment: you can do it in the function which is listening this event.